# Whats the best way to manage multiple webpack builds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, webpack, gruntjs

We have a pretty big web application that has about 10 websites served off of one codebase. We have multiple react apps, angular apps, legacy JS apps, etc.

We have 75% of our builds running in GruntJS and are just started to move over to webpack for the newer stuff. It's becoming very tricky to manage things, in Grunt we can easily have one huge config file for everything.

Webpack seems to not be that easy, as each application has different dependencies and vendor files.

Does anyone have any experience with managing multiple webpack configs for many applications in the same stack? I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of the week and feel quite frustrated.

Comment: Webpack configs are just plain objects. Use factories, classes or whatever to keep them DRY. There is webpack-merge package also. Depending on how the apps are built, you may want to use Webpack as a part of Gulp setup.